# Why does SparseArray allow some patterns but not others?

Tags: pattern-matching, sparse-arrays

When building a `SparseArray`, patterns of the form `{i_, i_}` and `{i_, j_}` are fine, but patterns like `{i_, 2 i_}` do not work:

> SparseArray::posd: The left-hand side of `{i_, 2 i_}->1` in `{{i_, 2 i_}->1}` is not a position or a pattern that will match the position of an element in an array with dimensions `{4,4}`.

```
m1 = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1}, {4, 4}];             (* OK *)
m2 = SparseArray[{{i_, 2 i_} -> 1}, {4, 4}];           (* error *)
m3 = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == 2 i -> 1}, {4, 4}]; (* OK *)
Map[MatrixForm, {m1, m2, m3}]
```

[image: Sparse arrays]

Why is this so? To me, `{i_, 2 i_} -> 1` is easier to read than `{i_, j_} /; j == 2 i -> 1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this reason

```
In[4]:= MatchQ[{1, 2}, {i_, 2 i_}]
Out[4]= False

In[5]:= MatchQ[{1, 2}, {i_, j_} /; j == 2 i]
Out[5]= True
```

Patterns are matched structurally, not mathematically.  You need to write the pattern is such a way that it actually matches in positions in the matrix.

Comment: Excellent answer. Very helpful.